# How can I group different equations into a single label using the amsmath package?

Tags: align, amsmath

Using the `align` environment provided by the `amsmath` package, I am running the following code with the intention to produce one single label for these three equations:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_{i1} - \beta_2 x_{i2} - ... - \beta_k x_{ik})^2 = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_{i1} - \beta_2 x_{i2} - ... - \beta_k x_{ik})^2 = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_{i1} - \beta_2 x_{i2} - ... - \beta_k x_{ik})^2 = 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, this is how the output looks like:

[image: output]

What code would output the same equations grouped under a single (3.3) label?

Comment: change `\begin{align}` to `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}`

Comment: And don't forget to match the new `\begin`s with the proper `\end`s.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Just curious: You employ an `align` environment yet don't provide any indications how the equations should be aligned. Should you maybe be using a `gather` environment?

Comment: The `gather` environment seems to only work in paragraph mode. From what I understand, it looks like inside the `equation` environment `align` is the way to go.